# Show that $Y_n=a_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i\xrightarrow{P}Y_\infty\implies Y_\infty$ is constant a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $Y_n=a_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ converges in probability to a random variable $Y_\infty$ for some constants $a_n\to0$. Show that $Y_\infty$ is almost surely equal to a constant.

I have been at this one for some time now with no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution to be a bit delicate so I wanted to post my solution in the hopes that it may help others in the future.

First, define for each $k\ge1$: $Y_n^k=a_n\sum\limits_{j=k}^{n}X_j$, then
\begin{align*}
Y_n^k=Y_n-a_nS_{k-1}\xrightarrow{P}Y_\infty\,\,\text{for all $k\ge1$, since $a_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}0\implies a_n\xrightarrow{P}0$}
\end{align*}
Now, for any $k$:
\begin{align*}
(\star)\,\,Y_n^k=funct(X_{k},...,X_n)\in\sigma(X_{k},...,X_n)\subseteq\sigma(X_k, X_{k+1},...)\,\,\text{for all $n\ge1$}
\end{align*}
What we want to show next is that $Y_\infty\in\sigma(X_k, X_{k+1},...)\,\,\text{for all $k$}.$ To this end, note that since $Y_n^k\xrightarrow{P}Y_\infty$, there exists a subsequence $Y_{n_j}^k$ such that $Y_{n_j}^k\xrightarrow{a.s.}Y_\infty\,\,\text{as $j\to\infty$}$. But by $(\star)$ we have that
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{j\to\infty}Y_{n_j}^k\in\sigma(X_k, X_{k+1},...)\,\,\text{for all $k$}\\
&\text{i.e.)}\,\,Y_\infty\in\sigma(X_k, X_{k+1},...)\,\,\text{for all $k$}\\
&\implies Y_\infty\in\bigcap_{k\ge1}\sigma(X_k, X_{k+1},...)\\
&\text{i.e.)}\,\,Y_\infty\in\tau,\,\,\text{the tail sigma algebra of the $X_n$}
\end{align*}
Thus, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that
\begin{align*}
P(Y_\infty\le x)=0\,\,\text{or}\,\,1
\end{align*}
That is, $Y_\infty$ has a degenerate distribution and so is almost surely equal to a constant, as we wished to show.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy consequence of Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. For any $k$ $Y_{\infty}$ is also the  limit of $a_n\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n}X_i$ so $Y_{\infty}$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma (X_k,X_{k+1},...)$. Hence it is  measurable w.r.t the tail sigma field. Since the tail sigma field is trivial it follows that $Y_{\infty}$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: Theres no issues with the fact that the convergence is in probability and not a.s.?

Comment: And is the fact that $a_n\to0$ not used?

Comment: Very much. The very first step requires this. I have used the fact that $a_nX_1 \to, a_nX_2 \to 0,..., a_nX_{k-1} \to 0$. @SpiderBite